# Subscribing to external ical programmatically

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps, icalendar

Through the Google Calendar UI a user can add an external iCAL calendar to their CalendarList.

When that Calendar is retrieved through CalendarList, the Calendar URL is not included. Additionally, it doesn't appear that it's possible to add an external iCal Calendar to a user's CalendarList.

Is this the case? Is there a way of programmatically subscribing a Google Calendar user to an external iCal feed?

---

Internally the Calendar UI uses the following URL to add an external calendar:

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/addcalendarfromurl

This URL takes the the following parameters by either POST or GET:

- **curl**: calendar url (url encoded).
- **cimp**: UI sets this to true, not sure what it does.
- **cpub**: true|false - make calendar public
- **secid**: security id from the client (session Id perhaps). Not specifying this brings a 403 error.

If the user isn't logged into the Calendar they will be redirected to the Google Login screen. If I had a way of generating a secid (perhaps OAUTH?), I could add a link to allow the user to add the calendar automatically.

Comment: I should add this is for an intranet application. We have external calendars we'd like to have automatically added to each user's CalendarList in Google Apps so they just appear for the user.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this issue? A last resort solution could be to use these format URLs https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?cid={{ICS_FEED_HERE}} to let users subscribe to calendars. This will open up a Yes/No visual prompt that the user can use to subscribe to the feed.

Comment: @bjornl your link no longer seems to work. Do you know of another one?

Comment: @bjornl the URL that you gave is exactly what I needed for publishing calendars from my app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any updates on Google Calendar API having an import .ics feature. [A ticket](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=210) has been logged since 2007 and still doesn't have any resolution as of this moment.

The only option I can find is to manually import the .ics file in the user's Google Calendar web UI. The [Import events to Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en) support page discusses the issue.

> *Step 2: Import events into Google Calendar*
>
> After you've exported your events, you can import them into Google Calendar.
>
> 1. Open Google Calendar on a computer. Note: You can only import from a computer, not a phone or tablet.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings settings gear button > Settings.
> 3. Open the Calendars tab.
> 4. Click Import calendars between the "My calendars" and "Other Calendars" sections.
> 5. Click Choose File and select the file you exported. The file should end in "ics" or "csv"
> 6. Choose which calendar to add the imported events to. By default, events will be imported into your primary calendar.
> 7. Click *Import*.
>
> If you're using a ZIP file, find it on your computer and open it. You'll see ICS files for each of your calendars. Take the individual files out of the ZIP file, and import each ICS file individually.
>
> *Note*: Repeating events might not show up that way if you import them from a CSV file, but they'll be on your calendar as a series of one-time events.

Comment: That ticket is for importing ICS files, this is about adding a Calendar Feed. So in the Calendar UI the "Add by URL" option rather than the "Import Calendar" option. I have created [an issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4388&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner) for this one too.